# Implement data change listener in a dialog box form

Tags: dialog, textfield, addeventlistener, codenameone

I had implemented a data change listener on a form and it worked very well, but when I tried implementing it on a form in a dialogue box it seems not to work. What might be the problem? Here is my code...

```
protected void onMain_AddMemberAction(final Component c, ActionEvent event) {

    //Show the dialog box that has the form.
    final Dialog d = (Dialog)createContainer(fetchResourceFile(), "GUI 1");
    d.show();
    //Listen to the data change on the text field.
    findPostalCode(c).addDataChangeListener(new textListener() {
      public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {
        //Run the following method  
         test(c); 
      }
  }); 

}

private abstract class textListener implements DataChangedListener {

}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

show is a blocking method so your listener is only registered after the dialog was disposed. Use `showModless`.